# Maven building a project using both Maven Dependencies and Referenced Libraries

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

Is there a command that will let Maven use the Referenced Libraries when building a project?

Comment: Declaring dependencies does this. Can you elaborate on your question and share the relevant parts of your POM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Dependencies section](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) of *Maven / POM Reference*:

> *The cornerstone of the POM is its dependency list. Most every project depends upon others to build and run correctly, and if all Maven does for you is manage this list for you, you have gained a lot. Maven downloads and links the dependencies for you on compilation and other goals that require them. As an added bonus, Maven brings in the dependencies of those dependencies (transitive dependencies), allowing your list to focus solely on the dependencies your project requires.*